# RadComboBox pre selection

Tags: c#, asp.net

First of all what I want to do is to pre select  a value in my RadComboBox ,and if this value is not selected something else is selected then change the visibility to of some specific fields  hidden.

My problem is that I'm able to make my pre select but somehow I can not change the status of my visibility for my specific fields when this pre selected value has changed.

What I have tired is to do it with a standard event **OnSelectedIndexChanged** but some how this is not triggering why so ever.. I have also added **AutoPostBack=true** as well as **ViewStateMode=Enabled"**

First my field's

Here comes my preslect as well here I would like to trigger the visibility change

```
  <div class="formRowDiv">
                        <asp:Label ID="Activitylbl" runat="server" Text="Activity" CssClass="formLabel" />
                        <telerik:RadComboBox ID="rcbActivity" CssClass="rowForm" ViewStateMode="Enabled" runat="server" Width="260px" EmptyMessage="- Activity -"
                            DataTextField="ActivityId" DataValueField="ActivityId" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rcbActivity_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        </telerik:RadComboBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="rcbActivity"
                            ErrorMessage="Can not be empty" CssClass="rowFormValidation" />
                    </div>
```

What I  want to hide:

```
<div class="formRowDiv">
                    <asp:Label ID="ActivityDescription" runat="server" Text="ActivityDescription" CssClass="formLabel"    Visible="false"/>
                    <telerik:RadTextBox runat="server" ID="rtbActivityDescription" Wrap="true" Height="50" TextMode="MultiLine" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="rowForm" ReadOnly="true" Visible="false" />
                </div>
```

How I do my  pre selection :

In my databind method that is called in my  Page_Load
I firrst loop and then do a pre select

```
   foreach (Activity item in ctx.Activity.OrderBy(l =>l.Code))
        {
            rcbActivity.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem(item.FullActivity, item.ActivityId.ToString()));

            if (rcbActivity.Items.FindItemByValue("4") != null)
            {
                rcbActivity.SelectedIndex = rcbActivity.Items.IndexOf(rcbActivity.Items.FindItemByValue("4"));
                ActivityDescription.Visible = true;
                rtbActivityDescription.Visible = true;
                rtbActivityDescription.ReadOnly = false;
            }
        }
```

Here is how I would hide my Fields

```
protected void rcbActivity_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e)
    {

            ActivityDescription.Visible = true;
            rtbActivityDescription.Visible = true;
            rtbActivityDescription.ReadOnly = false;
    }
```

Comment: are u using update panel?

Comment: @VishweshwarKapse I have add it it but its not helping

Comment: add a break point for you selected index changed method and see if it is getting hit and remove the update panel

Comment: @VishweshwarKapse sry the problem was the I set my Visibility to true but my visibility on my field is false so .. my fault but your solution with the Update panel is working fell free to post it as a answer !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case your controls are in an update panel then try removing it if the update panel is not so important and see if the changes u make to the controls in the server side are getting affected properly